# Lock view inside layout when keyboard appear

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I have an ImageView aligned on bottom of my layout contains "footer" of my app. Layout contains also ad EditText. Now when i tap on EditText and keyboard appear, it doesn't go over my footer, but footer get moved on above keyboard. There's a way to lock the imageView and get keyboard go over ImageView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this in your activity tag in the manifest `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"`

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Have a look at [`android:windowSoftInputMode` manifest attribute](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft). Specifically, consider using `adjustPan` there.